# Как определить причину ошибки Memtest86+?

Tags: железо

Периодически на компьютере стал появлятся синий экран смерти. По логом винды я понял, что причина в оперативной памяти. Провёл тест оперативки с помощью Memtest86+ V4.20.
Результат: [image: фото монитора]

Подробно об оперативной памяти:

- Имя модуляOCZ Gold XTC OCZ3G1333LV2G
- Размер модуля2 ГБ (1 rank, 8 banks)
- Установлено 3 модуля ОЗУ

Разгон не производился, настройки биоса стандартные. Компьютер собирал самостоятельно, до этого 3 года работал без ошибок.

Подскажите, как устранить проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я в таких случаях вставляю по одной планке, и делаю memtest для каждой.

Ошибка - прибить на стену.

Comment: Так и сделал. Одна платка даёт сбой.